List call records API returns 200 but no call records
I was using the List call records API with filter on participants (the participant ID below was copied from the document, I am using the correct one from my account)
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords?$filter=participants_v2/any(p:p/id eq '821809f5-0000-0000-0000-3b5136c0e777')
the REST API should return all call record for a specific participant in the last 30 days. It was working fine for me until this week. Now the API return code is 200, but no call records returns.
Any idea what happened?

Same issue here, using c# library.
Calling graphClient.Communications.CallRecords.GetAsync() does not return any result.
Calling a specify record returns the result correctly as always.
Last week both call works properly. Seems to be a Microsoft issue. Lets keep updated.
